# Serilog ignoring restrictedToMinimumlevel

Tags: serilog, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm using Serilog with ASP.NET Core 2.1. I want all log entries with a level of Information or higher to go to SQL Server and the console. I want only exceptions and higher to go to Email.

The Email sink is not being filtered and is also getting the same log entries as MSSQLServer and Console. It seems to be ignoring restrictedToMinimumlevel.

From my appsettings.json.

```
"Serilog": {
  "MinimumLevel": "Information",
  "WriteTo": [
    {
      "Name": "MSSqlServer",
      "Args": {
        "connectionString": "<removed>",
        "tableName": "Logs"
      }
    },
    {
      "Name": "Console"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Email",
      "Args": {
        "fromEmail": "<removed>",
        "toEmail": "<removed>",
        "mailServer": "<removed>",
        "mailSubject": "Test",
        "restrictedToMinimumlevel": "Error"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I expect it’s because you have a lowercase `l` at the start of what should be `Level`.

Comment: @KirkLarkin, Thanks, that was it!

Answer (score 1):

Serilog's setting of the configuration settings values is [case-sensitive](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/blob/9a46e68d3e224b965f4ac2665fd379ae9568d6b4/src/Serilog/Settings/KeyValuePairs/KeyValuePairSettings.cs#L241) and as such it's not able to find the `restrictedToMinimumlevel` argument because of that.

It should be `restrictedToMinimumLevel` with an uppercase `L` on `Level`.